# Is it safe to mount a TV below a window?

Tags: framing, mounting, television, home-theater

I have a spot in my bedroom where I'd like to mount a tv.

There is a wall with two closets on each side with a 4' space between them. The space has a built in chest that swings open at the top, and then a window about 2 feet above the chest. There is an outlet between the window and the chest, so presumably there is at least one stud there.

I want to mount the tv so I can still use the chest, but I'm worried about the load on that little stud below the window. Anyone know if this would be safe?

Comment: You're talking about a modern, flat screen TV?  Can't imagine one less than 4' wide being too heavy.  Is the wall standard sheetrock or some type of paneling?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yeah, flat screen, probably 48" or so, weighs ~50lbs, and the mount is pretty heavy too. It's old school thin wood paneling I think with regular drywall behind it. I'm just worried about the leverage. 50 pound tv hanging a foot or 16 inches away from the wall, could it cause the stud under the window to pull out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two options are to attach the TV mount to one stud (try to hit the center of the stud) or mount a board to the wall that hits more than one stud and then attach the TV mount to that (or get a TV mount made to pick up more than one stud).

For larger TV's I would want to hit at least two studs.  I looked up a random 43" TV on Amazon and it's weight was listed as 17lbs.  Unless it's a very old flat TV, it's going to be pretty light, and one stud with a strong mount should be fine.

Use a stud finder to get a general idea of where the stud is.  Then take a small drill bit (1/16" is fine) and drill a series of test holes to find the exact center of the stud.

[image]

*Picture from [another question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/119432/43874)*

Your window is higher, but the framing will be very similar.  The cripple stud under the window will be securely nailed into the sill plate.  That and the strength of the drywall will keep it from pulling out or moving.  When installed properly, studs and drywall are very strong.

Comment: I did get a mount that can hit two studs, but I'm not sure if there are two there. The one outlet under the window is pretty much centered, so I figured there might just be one cripple under there that the outlet is attached to. Guess I'll have to get the stud finder and see whats there.